# I am try to take a string and rebuild it with two random int values i created to swap two chars at those positions

Tags: java

```
public static String jumble(String s) {
  int length = s.length() - 2;
  Random r = new Random();
  int n = r.nextInt(2)+1;
  int a = r.nextInt(length)+1;
  String s1 ="";
  if (s.length() < 4) {
     s1 = s1 + s;
  } else if (s.length() == 4) {
     s1 = s1 + s.charAt(0);
     s1 = s1 + s.charAt(2);
     s1 = s1 + s.charAt(1);
     s1 = s1 + s.charAt(3);
  }
  while (n == a) {
     a = r.nextInt(length)+1;
  }
  if (0 < n && n < a && a < s.length()) {
     s1 = s1 + s.substring(0,n) + s.charAt(a) + s.substring(n + 1, a) + s.charAt(n) + s.substring(a+1,s.length());
  } 
  System.out.println(s1); 
  return s1;
```

this is my requirement

String jumble(String): accepts a string and returns a jumbled version of the original: for this method, jumbled means that two randomly chosen characters other than the first and last characters of the string are swapped; this method must use the class, Random. The method must swap two different characters: in other words the two random indices into the string cannot be equal, cannot be 0, and cannot be equal to the string’s length minus one. So, for example, a four-letter string MUST result in the returned string having the same first and last characters and have the second and third characters swapped. Examples of what this method might do: “fist” returns “fsit”, “much” returns “mcuh”, but for longer strings there will be more possible return values: “spill” could return “splil” or “sipll”. Only ONE pair of letters should be swapped and strings shorter than four characters are returned unchanged. When the string length is greater than 3, the original string must never be returned.

I have to use Random class and can only use the string class methods of length, charAt, and substring. this is what i have so far, I really need help creating the last string when it is greater than 4 and i need to use the random numbers i made.

Edit: I have got my code working better now, thanks to Ursa.  The problem i have now or at least I think it is a problem is that some times the code does not always print or return anything.

Comment: I'll just leave this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558454/i-need-to-use-the-random-class-to-jumble-the-middle-of-a-string. What is the current problem?

Comment: My current problem is with i guess jumbling a string with length greater than 4, or maybe just the idea of swapping characters in general. In my if (n != a && s.length() > 4 && a < n) { statement i got it to come up with the right swap, but i feel like its flawed thinking if the length of the string increases more.

Comment: the condition "When the string length is greater than 3, the original string must never be returned." is too strict. what should be returned for string "xyyyyyz"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1**

1. Wrap your input string with `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s);`
2. Get characters with `builder.charAt(int)` and compare them
3. Swap characters with `builder.setCharAt(int, char)`
4. Take result with `builder.toString()`

And you don't need to touch other characters.

**Approach #2**

At the first we should choose indexes of chars to swap:

```
// 0 < i1 < i2 < s.length - 1
int i1 = 1 + r.nextInt(s.length() - 3);           // 1 <= i1 <= s.length - 3
int i2 = 1 + i1 + r.nextInt(s.length() - i1 - 2); // i1 < i2 <= s.length - 2
```

Then we should split the string on intervals:

```
[0, i1)            - substring before the first swap char
{i1}               - the first swap char
[i1 + 1, i2)       - substring between swap chars
{i2}               - the second swap char
[i2 + 1, s.length) - substring after the second swap char
```

At last we should swap {i1} & {i2} chars:

```
return s.substring(0, i1) + s.charAt(i2) + s.substring(i1 + 1, i2) + s.charAt(i1) + s.substring(i2 + 1, s.length);
```

Comment: I can not use StringBuilder, at least my requirements seem to indicate I can not.

Comment: could you possibly clarify your second approach. I know this is a homework problem and I am not looking for a handout, but that second approach went right over my head.

Comment: I described it in details. try to make it by hands on paper with the example string (e.g. "asdfghj") - it would help you to understand the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public static String jumble(String s) {
        int length = s.length();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);

        int pos1 = getRandom(length);
        int pos2 = getRandom(length);

        while(pos1==pos2)
            pos1=getRandom(length);
        sb.setCharAt(pos1, s.charAt(pos2));
        sb.setCharAt(pos2, s.charAt(pos1));
          return new String(sb);
}

    private static int getRandom(int length) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand=r.nextInt(length);
        if(rand==0||rand==length)
            return getRandom(length);
        else
            return rand;
    }
```

Comment: @ursa yes that will be fine but still there is less posibilities of getting same number. anyway i will update it.

Comment: I can not use StringBuilder.